# KeyError at /videos/compose/ 'items'

Tags: json, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, youtube-data-api

Here I am working with YouTube Data API and am trying to get YouTube video titles with JSON, but am getting `KeyError at /videos/compose/ 'items'`.

Can you guys tell me what is wrong here; I have printed the variable `video_id` and that is correct, but still getting error on retrieving the title of a video.

`views.py`:

```
class VideoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Video
    form_class = VideoForm
    template_name = "videos/video_form.html"
    def form_valid(self, form):
        video = Video()
        video.url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        parse = urllib.parse.urlparse(video.url)
        video_id = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parse.query).get('v')
        if video_id:
            video.youtube_id =video_id[0]
            response = requests.get(f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={video_id[0]}&key=[{ YOUTUBE_API_KEY }]')
            json = response.json()
            title = json["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
            video.title = title
            video.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

`urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'videos'

urlpatterns = [
    path('compose/',views.VideoCreateView.as_view(),name='new'),
    path('video/<str:slug>/',views.VideoDetailView.as_view(),name='video_detail'),
]
```

If more code is require then tell me in a comment below; I will update my question with the needed information.

In the terminal, when I am printing the JSON response, that is showing me:

`{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.', 'errors': [{'message': 'API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}], 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}`,

but I am entering a correct `YOUTUBE_API_KEY`. Here it is:

```
import requests
import urllib


YOUTUBE_API_KEY = 'AIzaSyBdeXR_2YF4***IIeywL08JSUm2zc*******'
```

Comment: try to dump `response.json()` , and be sure if there's a key with name of `items`.

Comment: see i have add some more info in question

Comment: Show your code defining `key`, please. (But not the key value itself!)

Comment: Or is that API key placed as such within the string `f'https://...&key=...'`?

Comment: i have add that in my question ,check that

Comment: The have your URL string as `f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={video_id[0]}&key={YOUTUBE_API_KEY}'`. Notice the removed square brackets and spaces around `YOUTUBE_API_KEY`.

Comment: yeah i remove those brackets and get **IndexError at /videos/compose/

list index out of range** , do you know anything about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the output produced by the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint when passing to an invalid API key as in the URLs shown:

1. Empty `key`:

```bash
$ wget -qO- --content-on-error \
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=foobar&part=snippet&key="
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

2. `key` is `barbaz`:

```
$ wget -qO- --content-on-error \
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=foobar&part=snippet&key=barbaz"
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

To fix your code do have your URL string as:

`f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={video_id[0]}&key={YOUTUBE_API_KEY}'`.

Notice the removed square brackets and spaces around `YOUTUBE_API_KEY`.

---

Here is the output produced by the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint when passing to it an invalid video ID as in the URL shown (presupposing that the value of the parameter `key` is a valid API key):

```bash
$ wget -qO- --content-on-error \
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=foobar&part=snippet&key=..."
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "...",
  "items": [],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  }
}
```

Do notice that the `items` array is empty. This explains the `IndexError` exception obtained by your code.

The fix of your code is as follows:

```
json = response.json()
items = json["items"]
assert len(items) <= 1
if len(items):
    title = items[0]["snippet"]["title"]
else:
    title = "N/A"
```

You could also produce some kind of error message in case `len(items) == 0`; that has the following meaning: *the video referred by the given ID does not exist.*

Comment: Brother this is working fine but there is one bug with this , Actually it is saving two objects at same time but one with fields which contain data of video and other one is blank , Why this is happening , I am adding screenshots with some detail ,so you can understand what is happening

Comment: @Ahmed: that issue is very much likely due to things that are not shown by the code you posted within your question. I suggest to investigate a bit further and then post a new question targeting specifically that unexpected behavior (also showing more source code context for that matter).

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64730061/objects-are-twicely-storing-into-django-database-when-a-single-object-is-created) here i asked new question ,check now and answer if you figure out the problem.