# How can I fix the issue of objects being stored twice in Django database?

Tags: json, django, ajax, django-models, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube Data API to create an object, but when I create a single object, it creates two objects - one with the proper details and one that is blank. How can I resolve this issue?

**before creating object**
[image]

**after creating single object**
[image]

I am trying with the following code.
view.py

```
class VideoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Video
    form_class = VideoForm
    template_name = "videos/video_form.html"
    def form_valid(self, form):
        video = Video()
        video.url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        parse = urllib.parse.urlparse(video.url)
        video_id = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parse.query).get('v')
        if video_id:
            video.youtube_id =video_id[0]
            response = requests.get(f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={video_id[0]}&key={YOUTUBE_API_KEY}')
            json = response.json()
            items = json["items"]
            assert len(items) <= 1
            if len(items):
                title = items[0]["snippet"]["title"]
                video.title = title
                video.save()
            else:
                title = "N/A"
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):

    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    youtube_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("videos:video_detail", kwargs={"slug":self.slug})


        
def video_pre_save_reciever(sender,instance,*args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(video_pre_save_reciever,Video)
```

if more code is require than tell me in comment , i will update my question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

The view `VideoCreateView` inherits `CreateView`. `CreateView` inherits `ModelFormMixin` which defines `form_valid` method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
    self.object = form.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

You save the video object and call the super form_valid which saves the form(in turn creating a model object) again. Hence, causing a double creation. I suggest modifying the form and passing it to super instead of manually saving it.

Another option is to inherit the View with `django.views.generic.View`. This would avoid form save.

I suggest you follow the first approach.

Comment: I try this and this is still storing twice object ,please answer me by the changes in my required code ,

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this my problem by removing all the form_valid code from the views and add that inside the model

```
class Video(models.Model):

    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
    youtube_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        
        parse = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.url)
        video_id = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parse.query).get('v')
        if video_id:
            self.youtube_id =video_id[0]
            response = requests.get(f'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={video_id[0]}&key={YOUTUBE_API_KEY}')
            json = response.json()
            title = json["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
            self.title = title
        super(Video,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```